# How to store p12 file in Git repository using Fastlane?

Tags: git, apple-push-notifications, fastlane, fastlane-match

I'm using [Fastlane Match](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/match) to manage my certificates and provisionings on iOS.
This tool is so cool that I would like to inspire me to manage my push notification certicates and p12.

I'm using pem to create the p12 file, and I would like to store it, in my git repo, with the others certificates.

I have no idea how to do :

- create my own fastfile?
- create my own fastlane plugin?

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a Fastfile, you can run `fastlane init` from your project directory. To create a `fastlane plug_in`, you can run `fastlane new_plugin` from your project directory.

[Here are instructions to create a new plugin](https://docs.fastlane.tools/plugins/create-plugin/).

[Here are instructions to set up your project for fastlane](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#setting-up-fastlane).

Comment: I see this answer was down-voted as "not useful". It seems that I am providing a useful instructions, so I'm confused. Can the person who down-voted it clarify why this is not useful?

Comment: Thanks, I will fix it when I get on a computer

Comment: Link to plugin creation fixed.